find a non-constant function in $\mathbb{R}^2$
Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ .
Find a non-constant function $u$ which is defined on an $\Omega$ of $ \mathbb{R}^2$ with value in $\mathbb{R}$ such that: $u=0$ on the boundary and $ \nabla u=0$ on the boundary of $\Omega$ and all partial derivatives coincide in $\Omega$.
I have already try the function $u(x,y)=(1-(x+y))^2 \quad \in \Omega$ . Where $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x+y< 1\}$, But the problem here is the domain is not bounded!!
my question can i find such function in a bounded domain.
Thank's a lot.

What precisely do you mean by all partial derivatives? And what makes you think this result can possibly be obtained?

I second the question by Ted. If by "all partial derivatives coincide in $\Omega$" you mean $u_x(x,y)=u_y(x,y)$, for all $(x,y)\in\Omega$, then $\Omega$ can't be bounded. This essentially tells us that directional derivative of $u$ along $(1,-1)$ is $0$, so $u$ is constant along the lines parallel to $(1,-1)$. If $\Omega$ were bounded, for any $(x,y)\in\Omega$, we'd have that there exists $(x+T,y-T)\in\partial\Omega$ and $(x+t,y-t)\in\Omega$ for $t\in[0,T)$, so $u(x,y) = u(x+T,y-T) = 0$. That is, if $\Omega$ is bounded, $u$ vanishes on whole of $\Omega$.

So, you want $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \Omega$ and $\nabla u(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \partial \Omega$ for some let's say function $u \in C^1(\overline \Omega)$.
By change of coordinates $(\tilde x, \tilde y) = (x+y,y)$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ the differential equation turns into $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \tilde y}(\tilde x,\tilde y) = 0$. So the problem is equivalent to the problem (by changing $\Omega$ to $\tilde \Omega$):
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \Omega$ and $\nabla u(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y) \in \partial \Omega$ for some function $u \in C^1(\overline \Omega)$.
W.l.o.g. assume that $\Omega$ is connected. Then the differential equation is equivalent to $u(x,y) = g(x)$ for some $g \in C^1(\omega)$, where $\omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open with $\pi_1(\overline \Omega) \subseteq \omega$ and $\pi_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, \ (x,y) \mapsto x$ is the natural projection.
Now it must also be $0=\nabla u(x,y) = g'(x)$ for all $(x,y) \in \partial \Omega$. Thus $g' = 0$ on $\pi_1(\partial \Omega)$. If $\Omega$ is bounded it holds $\pi_1(\overline\Omega) = \pi_1(\partial \Omega)$. Therefore $g = c$ is constant (with some $c \in \mathbb{R}$) on $\pi_1(\overline \Omega)$ and thus $u(x,y) = g(x) = c$ for all $(x,y) \in \overline \Omega$, i.e. $u = c$ is constant.
Thus there is no such non-constant function.
